# Angular - Restarting a css animation

Tags: angular, css-animations

Given the following example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4twwo

I would like to be able to restart the animation of this svg upon method call.

Currently within my application I have a `check` and a `cross`, these should be re-animated based on the result of an api request which occurs every 30 seconds.

---

As there was some confusion I have added both check and cross now. There are methods in both `component.ts` files and one in `app.component.ts` which can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the code changes for you please check it

`https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-le5nbe?file=src/app/app.component.html`

You can switch the status according to your API response

These changes can be used as per your API response.

```
  status = 'check';

  fnCheck(){
    this.status = 'check';
  }

  fnCross(){
    this.status = 'cross';
```

I have added `check` svg for your help and added 2 buttons for events ( In your case your can call those methods based on the API response)

```
<svg #cross *ngIf="status == 'cross'" class="cross" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
    <circle class="cross__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
    <path class="cross__line" fill="none" d="M36 16 16 36" />
    <path class="cross__line2" fill="none" d="M16 16 36 36" />
</svg>

<svg #right *ngIf="status == 'check'" class="cross" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
    <circle class="cross__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
    <path d="M36.285 16l-11.285 11.567-5.286-5.011-3.714 3.716 9 8.728 15-15.285z"/>
</svg>

<button (click)='fnCheck()' >Check</button>
<button (click)='fnCross()' >Cross</button>
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Sorry but perhaps my question was not clear. I have a different component for check, and a different one for cross. I would like to be able to call "restart" on the component and have the animation play from the beginning. I have updated the stackblitz for clarity.

Comment: Both the Cross & Check will be rendered separately or both will be there on the page simultaneously?

Comment: Check the updated link `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-le5nbe?file=src/app/app.component.html`

Comment: @Rohit.007 Sorry, I didn't see your replies as I wasn't tagged. Thanks for the update!